A proper subgroup of rational numbers which is not cyclic
How do we prove that the dyadic rationals $\{ \frac{a}{2^n} : a,n \in \mathbb{Z} \}$ is a "proper" subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}$?

Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Are you having trouble proving it’s a subgroup or proving it’s “proper” [sic]?

For the "proper" part, consider whether $\frac{1}{3}$ is in this set.

@J.W.Tanner  Thank you! My problem is proving that it's "proper".

@ljfirth Thank you, I was thinking too hard about it.

Does this answer your question?
